Was liegt Namensbildungen wie "Goethen" statt "Goethe" oder "Charlotten" statt "Charlotte" zugrunde?
Was liegt Namensbildungen wie "Goethen" statt "Goethe" oder "Charlotten" statt "Charlotte" zugrunde und wo werden sie historisch eingeordnet?
Und gibt es solche Bildungen auch bei Namen ohne Vokal am Ende?

Kannst du bitte konkrete Beispiele für solche Abwandlungen geben? Mir sind solche Modifikationen nämlich völlig unbekannt. Kann es sein, dass das ein regional begrenztes Phänomen der Umgangssprache ist? Ich bin aus Österreich und ich lese in der Antwort von Alazon einen Vergleich mit der Phrase "wie bei Muttern", die bei uns in Österreich völlig ungebräuchlich, aber durch deutsche Medien, die auch in Österreich konsumiert werden, wenigstens bekannt ist. »Goethen« oder »Charlotten« kenne ich gar nicht.

Ich habe diese Bildungen bei Goethe selbst, sowie bei Thomas Mann gefunden.

Kannst du bitte konkrete Beispiele (wörtliche Zitate samt Quellenangabe) für solche Abwandlungen geben?

Du meinst Belege wie:

Döbereiner war von Runges Versuchen an Katzenaugen so beeindruckt, dass er sprach: »Sie sind von der höchsten Wichtigkeit, und noch heute Abend werde ich Goethen davon erzählen.« (Beleg aus https://www.nd-aktuell.de/artikel/86651.goethe-und-das-koffein.html)

Das sind alte Dativ- und Akkusativformen der Eigennamen "Goethe, Charlotte". Im Beispiel oben ist "Goethen" ja Dativobjekt von "erzählen". Freistehend kommen die Formen  auf -n m.W. nicht vor.
Die Dudengrammatik (2022, S. 584) erwähnt das, und in diesem Zusammenhang auch die Wendung "wie bei Muttern", da ist das alte -n auch erhalten geblieben.

Gibt es das auch bei Namen ohne Vokalendung?

@Karl, ja, und das ist besonders beim Genitiv interessant, weil es erklärt, was es mit dem Apostroph bei manchen Personennamen auf sich hat, wie zum Beispiel bei Hans’ Auto. Der Apostroph ist ja ein Auslassungzeichen, doch was wurde bei Hans’ ausgelassen? Ganz einfach: Die alte Genitivform lautete Hansens, und der Apostroph kennzeichnet die Auslassung von -ens.

Ah, daran habe ich gar nicht gedacht. Sagte man dann damals beim Genitiv "Goethens" oder "Goethes" Buch?
